# How to force a einstein bot snap-in to check if the user has logged in mid chat session

Tags: liveagent, einstein, snap-ins, bots

I have an Einstein Bot use case scenario where Users are supposed to start the chat session without a need to login to my salesforce site but later, depending on the confidentiality of the information requested they may be asked to login. So once the user logs in during a chat session how do I instruct the bot / snap-in to check the login status of the currently engaged user.

Are there any events on embedded_svc that can be triggered on refresh of the VF page hosting the snap-in to achieve this?